# cannot serialize map containg orientdb record id

Tags: java, nosql, orientdb

Just migrated orientdb from v2.1.19 to v3.0.2 and there is an issue with the code I was using.

Basically doing this now throws a cast exception  :

```
Map<String, String> myMap = vertex.getProperty("myMap");
String test = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myMap);
```

**Where**

- `myMap` : Embedded map property of the `vertex` vertex in the orientdb database.
- `ObjectMapper` : `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` the serializer provided by Jackson.

**Full error label** : `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.id.ORecordId cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Why is it that `ORecordId` can not be cast to `String` anymore ?

**Only solution I see** : detect that there is a `ORecordId` in the map and transform it manually into a `String`. This doesn't seem like a fit to me.

Answer (score 1):

**The solution I used** (I'm not really fond of it)

I created a method that handle the retrieved property as `Map<String, Object>`

```
public static Map<String, String> convertToStringMap(Map<String, Object> map) {
    if (map == null)
        return null;
    return map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            entry -> entry.getKey(), 
            entry -> entry.getValue().toString()));
}
```

Then I can retrieve my embedded map as a `Map<String, String>` this way

```
Map<String, String> myMap = convertToStringMap(vertex.getProperty("myMap"))

// Do something with
// (both throw an exception if no passed through convertToStringMap)
String test = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myMap); // serialize
System.out.println(my.get("anEntryKey")); // print
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, very useful!